# mysql show databases by condition

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have databases named like this:

```
    database_100
    database_120
    database_153
    database_143
    ...
```

I'll call the numbers at the end 'Databse ID' for the sake of this example.

Doing something like `SHOW DATABASES LIKE "database_%` will output all the DBs and it's fine. Now I want to show databases with `id = 100 or 120 or 320` this is just an example, the list of IDs itself is dynamically pulled from an array.

How can I do something like that?

EDIT:

I'm trying to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` from `SCHEMATA` WHERE `SCHEMA_NAME` LIKE "database_%";
```

but still can't figure out how to select by the dynamic IDs.

I'm thinking about something like (in pseudo code):

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` from `SCHEMATA` WHERE `SCHEMA_NAME` LIKE "database_$var" WHILE $var in (121, 153, 143);
```

Could it be done only in SQL ?

Comment: I don't believe MySQL supports dynamic sql. Why not you can use prepare statement.?? try this link  http://rpbouman.blogspot.in/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use prepare statement ,Try the below code it will resolve your issue...
However you need modify this line `set @schema := 'tes%';` according to your requirement

```
 mysql> USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA
    Database changed
    mysql> prepare stmt from
        -> 'SELECT SCHEMA_NAME from SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME like ?';
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
    Statement prepared

    mysql> set @schema := 'tes%';
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

    mysql> execute stmt using @schema;
    +-------------+
    | SCHEMA_NAME |
    +-------------+
    | test        |
    +-------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```